# Add custom image to items on Ext.tab.Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I want to add some customs images on the navigation items on [Ext.tab.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel).

I know, that there are a few images available if you use the `iconCls`.

```
items: [
    {
        title: 'Home',
        iconCls: 'home',
        html: 'Home Screen'
    },
    {
        title: 'Contact',
        iconCls: 'user',
        html: 'Contact Screen'
    }
]
```

How can I proceed? Is there a image property or something else, or do I have to write my own CSS classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css way, or use some of the icons included in the core, there a lot :)

view:

```
iconCls: 'myTab'
```

css:

```
.myTab {
   background-image: url("resources/images/myTab.png");
}
```

Comment: replace -webkit-mask-box-image with background-image